# Google Firebase Auth in my react Application

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Google Auth in my REact Application. I have enabled my Authentication for Google on Fire base console. But I get an error:
code: "auth/operation-not-allowed"
message: "The identity provider configuration is not found."

Please suggest

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nf4eB.png)

Comment: Have you enabled the specific provider that you want to use for authentication? It looks here like you're using email/password, so check that in the Firebase Console under Authentication > Sign-in method the Email/Password row says Enabled.

Answer (score 2):

According to Firebase Docs,

> **auth/operation-not-allowed**:
>   Thrown if you have not enabled the provider in the Firebase Console. Go to the Firebase Console for your project, in the Auth section and the Sign in Method tab and configure the provider. *https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Error*

[Is your Google provider enabled in your Firebase console as shown in this image?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4Cyx.png)

Comment: Thank you yes I had to enable the provider in Firebase.